# How to transfer files I created programmatically back to my PC?

Tags: file-system, storage, file-transfer

I created JSON files on my Android using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33572815/1075211

The files are now stored in /data/user/0/com.xxxxx.collector.

But how do I now transfer those files to my PC?

Comment: I don't get it why my answer was being closed. I need to get data from my phone. I've seen a dozen questions covering ADB and stuff already

Answer (score 1):

You have saved the file in athe app-private directory. As it name indicates it is private therefore you can't access any files in there unless you have rooted your phone (or use the work-around via `adb backup` and then extract the backup using [ABE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor)).

If you want to save a file that will be copied later outside of your phone save it onto the sd-card section `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Then you can pull it from the device via `adb pull`.

Comment: So I need an SD card?

Comment: No. getExternalStorageDirectory() usually points to the internal storage.